# Javascript can't find certain html elements

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm putting together some offline technical documentation, and so have written some javascript for very basic syntax highlighting, and now for convenience I'm using it to replace `<` and `>` characters to save me time having to manually escape them.

The problem is this works great for a lot of html tags, except for `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` blocks.

The HTML within the `<code>` blocks are present in the DOM, but JS doesn't seem to find them.

I understand the HTML in question is not valid, but given it is present when I view the page source, shouldn't it still be found?

```js
function stringReplace(str,from,to) {
  if (str) return str.replace(from,to)
}
var htmlChars = [
  ["<", "&lt;"],
  [">", "&gt;"]
];

function escapeHtmlChars(elementTagName, chars) {
  var codeSections = document.getElementsByTagName(elementTagName);
  for (var i = 0; i < codeSections.length; i++) {
    var codeContent = codeSections[i].innerHTML;
    for (var j = 0; j < chars.length; j++) {
      codeContent = stringReplace(codeContent, chars[j][0], chars[j][1])
      codeSections[i].innerHTML = codeContent;
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log(
    escapeHtmlChars("code", htmlChars)
  )  
});
```

```html
<code class="code-snippet"><!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css"></style>
        </head>
    
        <body>
    
        </body>
    </html>
    </code>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with your version of stringReplace

Comment: html, body and head tags are stripped by browser if they are not escaped, so by the time you are calling your function, those tags doesnt exist.

Comment: *The HTML within the <code> blocks are present in the DOM* On my browser (Firefox) they are not present

Comment: Ah, within Chrome I can see it. @AvcS thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand the HTML in question is not valid, but given it is present when I view the page source, shouldn't it still be found?

No, because your JavaScript isn't interacting with the source code.

The browser reads the source code. It constructs a DOM from it (which involves a **lot** of error recovery rules). You then read the `innerHTML` which generates HTML from the DOM.

The original data isn't available because the error recovery has already been applied.

> now for convenience I'm using it to replace < and > characters to save me time having to manually escape them

I suggest generating your HTML from Markdown files to save on the effort there. Alternatively, set up a *Find & Replace in selection* macro in your editor.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes perfect sense. Since I'm doing this just to save time I think your suggestion regarding my text editor is a much better idea. I'm going to end up spending more time doing this any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Since these tags are stripped when rendered, you should use AJAX to get at the documents and convert them when you receive them.

Alternatively: Although `XMP` is obsolete this still works in my browser

```js
var html = document.querySelector("xmp").textContent
console.log(html)
document.querySelector("code").innerHTML = html.replace(/<(\/)?(\w+)/g,"<br/>&lt;$1$2")
```

```css
xmp { display: none }
code { white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<xmp class="code-snippet">
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
</xmp>
<code></code>
```